# Send picture id from fragment to another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi everyone I have a problem with sending picture id using intent from fragment to another activity, I searched about the problem I saw that intent send id as double not int any idea how to share picture id between activities. this question is the same as my problem but the solution didn't work for me: [How can i get Image Resource ID and send it to other activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392521/how-can-i-get-image-resource-id-and-send-it-to-other-activity-in-android). 
here's my program

```
public class BestTenPlaces extends Fragment {

public BestTenPlaces() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    final View detailsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
    ArrayList<InfoObject> objects = new ArrayList<InfoObject>();
    objects.add(new InfoObject("baghdad 1", "gitnge", R.drawable.capture));
    objects.add(new InfoObject("string 2", "gitnge", R.drawable.capture));
    objects.add(new InfoObject("string 3", "gitnge", R.drawable.capture));
    objects.add(new InfoObject("string 4", "gitnge", R.drawable.capture));
    objects.add(new InfoObject("string 5", "gitnge", R.drawable.capture));
    objects.add(new InfoObject("string 6", "gitnge", R.drawable.capture));
    final ArrayList<InfoObject> details = new ArrayList<InfoObject>();
    details.add(new InfoObject("string 1", R.drawable.capture));
    details.add(new InfoObject("string 2", R.drawable.capture));
    details.add(new InfoObject("string 3", R.drawable.capture));
    details.add(new InfoObject("string 4", R.drawable.capture));
    details.add(new InfoObject("string 5", R.drawable.capture));
    details.add(new InfoObject("string 6", R.drawable.capture));
    GeneralAdapter BestPlaces = new GeneralAdapter(getActivity(),                                                 objects);
    ListView BestPlacesList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    BestPlacesList.setAdapter(BestPlaces);
    BestPlacesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            InfoObject detailsArray = details.get(position);
            String m = detailsArray.getmTextDetails();
            int s = (int) detailsArray.getImageResourcesObject();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), details.class);
            intent.putExtra("message", m);
            intent.putExtra("resource", s);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

and here is the activity

```
public class details extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    int resources = extra.getInt("resource");
    String message = bundle.getString("message");
    TextView textDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_details);
    textDetails.setText(message);
    ImageView imageDetails = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_details);
    imageDetails.setImageResource(resources);
}
}
```

here's the InfoObject

```
public class InfoObject {
private String locationObject;
private String placeNameObject;
private int imageResourcesObject;
private String mTextDetails;
private int mDetailsImageResource;

public InfoObject(String location, String placeName, int imageResources) {
    locationObject = location;
    placeNameObject = placeName;
    imageResourcesObject = imageResources;
}

public InfoObject(String textDetails, int detailsImageResource) {
    mTextDetails = textDetails;
    mDetailsImageResource = detailsImageResource;
}

public String getmTextDetails() {
    return mTextDetails;
}

public int getmDetailsImageResource() {
    return mDetailsImageResource;
}

public String getLocationObject() {
    return locationObject;
}

public String getPlaceNameObject() {
    return placeNameObject;
}

public int getImageResourcesObject() {
    return imageResourcesObject;
}

public void setLocationObject(String locationObject) {
    this.locationObject = locationObject;
}

public void setPlaceNameObject(String placeNameObject) {
    this.placeNameObject = placeNameObject;
}

public void setImageResourcesObject(int imageResourcesObject) {
    this.imageResourcesObject = imageResourcesObject;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting `"message"` (`textDetails` TextView) fine at the `details` activity?

Comment: yes I get the message in "textDetails" TextView but I don't get the Image Id

Comment: Please post source code of `InfoObject`.

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're populating the array `details` in `onCreateView` method, you're using the following constructor of `InfoObject`:

```
new InfoObject("string 3", R.drawable.capture)
```

This constructor initializes the field  `mDetailsImageResource` NOT `imageResourcesObject` which you later try to read from.

Since uninitialized `int` class members in Java will be initialized to `0` automatically, when you try to read from `imageResourcesObject` it's `0`.

Comment: Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your methods, they will be more effective.
For example, let's pass on the message. Basically, you will be sending a string to a new activity from a fragment.

In the fragment, call:

```
intent.putExtra("message", detailsArray.getmTextDetails());
```

Then in Activity:

```
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra().getString("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead in Details Activity**

```
int resources = getIntent().getIntExtra("resource", 0);
String message = getIntent().getString("message");
```

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by proper way:

1. make one interface that has method which can call from fragment.
2. in your activity implement this interface
3. from your fragment make object of interface in your `onAttach()` method which give activity context.
4. with the help of this object `onActivityCreated()` call your method.